# Postdoc wanting to go to industry - need advice

Tags: phd, job-search, job

I have been a STEM postdoc for almost 7 years. I am based in Australia and currently looking for a permanent position, preferably in industry. As I have not done this transition, I would appreciate it if anyone who has done this can share their experience, and address my question below.

My question is: given that by having a STEM education one has developed multiple skills (e.g., research, writing, project management, analytical thinking, data analysis, as well as advanced maths and statistical skills), is it an effective strategy to apply to any job that makes use of some combination of the above skills, with suitably tailored resume and cover letter for each application?

I am asking this because due to my time constraints, I am weighing between applying to many industries or focussing on one or two industries and networking in those areas.

Comment: I'm surprised that your time, rather than the number of desirable positions that you know about, is the limiting factor. Are there really so many jobs that appeal to you? Or are you desperate and you need to find something ASAP?

Comment: With all due respect, it sounds like you first have to decide what it is that you want to contribute in an industry-type job. A PhD in STEM doesn't make yu a jack of all trades. Take the time to see whether there is something that you like to do, do the necessary training for it, and apply. Not the other way around.

Comment: You might consider a postdoc at a company or government lab. The former often views postdocs as ‘extended interviews,’ and the experience might give you the opportunity to explore your options and your own talents.

Answer (score 6):

> Is it an effective strategy for one to just apply to any job that makes use some combination of the above skills, with suitably tailored résumé and cover letter for each application?

Yes, with caveats. There's a good chance the first screen will be from a HR executive who'll be looking to see if you meet their "on paper" qualifications, e.g. if you look at [this advertisement](https://www.recruit.net/job/business-development-specialist-jobs/1AA8EDDEB31B1E1E) you can see that they are looking for:

> Preferred 3-5 years shown experience in business development, sales or account relationship management, experience in instrumentation solutions sales preferably in the analytical instruments (Mass Spectrometry) sector will be highly regarded.  A shown understanding of NZ market and workflows is desired.
>
> Preferred tertiary qualifications to be in science with strong analytical science, proteomics, chemistry knowledge highly regarded.

As a STEM postdoc you probably will not have the first paragraph's experience, but you will pass the second one. If the first paragraph's experience is a hard requirement, then the HR executive might exclude you in the first screening and you never make it pass the first stage. Accordingly, ideally you apply to any job that uses some combination of the skills you have, *and* lists your paper qualifications as desirable.

Comment: Now, if one were a postdoc working on developing novel measurements using one of their mass specs (including interactions with field service) you would be a shoo-in

Answer (score 6):

It sounds to me like you should start with [informational interviews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informational_interview) before starting applications. Your goal in these interviews would be not to apply for a specific job, but to discuss your resume, skills, and interests with people who are more familiar with work in industry and who can help point you to the types of positions you would qualify for (and maybe even suggest specific jobs to apply for).

The challenge of informational interviews is figuring out who's willing to spend the time talking to you. The institution you're working at (or past institutions) may be able to connect you with people; there may be student organizations for those intending to enter certain professions that have industry connections and these may be available to you even as a post doc (or they may at least be willing to circulate your contact info).

Another place to start would be any of your previous academic colleagues who now work in industry: very few people are able to stay in academia and if you've been a post doc for 7 years you have anyone you were a colleague with during your PhD as well as anyone from that post doc period that has gone on to industry.

Other connections are your casual network: friends and friends of friends. Ask other people about their jobs and job searches outside of academia. Ask whether you can have a deeper conversation about your goals and interests, or for people to connect you with others they know that would be a good resource.

Answer (score 3):

I did my PhD in stem after several years of work in industry. Before I even submitted thesis I got a new job in industry (UK). I applied for a very remotely linked field to my PhD (or any of my previous work for that matter). Now I know that I got the job because they were looking for someone with a broad experience in multiple sectors.
So I would say if you don't like your area and want a change it's possible to transition from academia and from your field at the same time. I wouldn't apply for multiple unrelated jobs within a small network though because you may get noticed in a negative way.